# Basic SQL query on JOIN and ORDER BY

Tags: sql

Just playing around with SQL after a long time and I seem to be stuck at the following:
I have 2 tables **'User' = (U_ID, Name, Address)** and **'Book' = (B_ID, Name, Date_Issued, U_ID)** and I need to display the last book issued by all the users in the database.
The query I wrote is,

```
SELECT TOP 1 User.Name, Book.Name, Book.Date_Issued
FROM User,
INNER JOIN Book,
WHERE User.U_ID = Book.U_ID
ORDER BY Book.Date_Issued
```

Is this even vaguely correct (syntax may not be 100% correct)? Can Order By be used on a column with Date/Time?
Thanks for the help (in advance :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add order by  type

```
ORDER BY Book.Date_Issued DESC
```

SQL ORDER BY clause, the sort order is defaulted to ASC or ascending order.
if Date_Issued is not Date datatype, then parse it .

```
ORDER BY to_date(Date_Issued ,'mm/dd/yyyy') DESC //for sql.
```

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten the DESC (duh!)

Comment: @Manasi Accept the answer as valid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes order by works with Date/Time.
Change your code as follow:

```
SELECT TOP 1 User.Name, Book.Name, Book.Date_Issued
FROM User,
INNER JOIN Book,
WHERE User.U_ID = Book.U_ID
ORDER BY Book.Date_Issued DESC
```